# “The colour of (the) water(s)”

Tags: articles, plural-forms, countability

'Waters' in this context confuses me

First, let's look at two relevant definition/meanings of **plural waters** found in the *Oxford Learner's Dictionaries*.

> **3.** waters [plural] – the water in a particular lake, river, sea or ocean
>
> **5.** [waters](http://www.oxfordlearnersdictionaries.com/definition/english/water_1) [plural] – an area of sea or ocean belonging to a particular country

I got it.

Now the confusion – what should replace 'X', 'Y', 'Z' in the example below: *water* or *waters*?

> The color of (the?) **X** is magenta because at that place, (the?) **Y** of Indian Ocean and (the?) **Z** of South Atlantic Ocean which are red and green respectively meet.

Also, does it take the article *the*? Because in one official document from the Journal of Marine Research (American Government), I found this sentence (without *the*) -

> ...*continues into the Indian Ocean while the rest of it mixes with **water of Indian Ocean**...*

Answer (score 7):

> The colour of the **(X)** is magenta because

The word for (X) here is indisputably "water", as it is referring to the actual substance in the sea.

> at that place, the **(Y)** of the Indian Ocean and the **(Z)** of the South Atlantic Ocean meet.

Here, you can use the "water" to refer to the actual substance in the oceans, or "waters" to refer to the abstract body of water in each case. Since it says that the two oceans *meet* in the plural form, you want something that will convey distinct objects, so it is probably better to use the countable *waters* here.

This gives you the final form of:

> The colour of the **water** is magenta because at the place, the **waters** of the Indian Ocean and the **waters** of the South Atlantic Ocean, which are red and green respectively, meet.

Answer (score 2):

[Original [answer](https://ell.stackexchange.com/revisions/20521/1)]

1. "The waters of Egypt are filled with crocodiles"

Use *waters* when referring to a grouping of bodies of water. Much in the same sense you would use *river*.

2. "The rivers of England run dry"
   "All the rivers in England are dry"

> "The color of **the water** is magenta because **the waters** of the Indian **and** the Southern Atlantic Ocean, which are red and green respectively, meet."

Bear in mind "color" is the American spelling of "colour" which is British English.

Comment: This does not answer the question. Thanks for info though

Comment: The color of the water is magenta because the waters of the Indian and the Southern Atlantic Ocean, which are red and green respectively, meet.

Comment: Kindly edit and add this. This'd be then answer and not vulnerable to get closed.

Comment: The sentence given as an answer is correct, but it really should contain information on *why* it is correct. Without that information, it is unlikely to help Maulik or any future visitors.

Comment: Also, to the NAA flaggers: http://meta.stackexchange.com/a/185074/228098. The flag is NOT used to indicate technical inaccuracies or deficiencies in a post. If you feel that the post is badly researched, explained, or written, you should downvote, comment, or edit.