# Water, a water and waters

Tags: plural-forms, uncountable-nouns, countability

*1. Water boils at 100°c.*

*2. Still waters run deep.*

Based on the two sentences we can say that water is both uncountable and countable.If water is countable "a water" should be there as in the case of "fish". we can say fish, fishes and a fish.

I would like to ask how it is possible to use plural form  for "water".

A little water and a little sugar are possible but we can not say "a sugar" and "a water"

Is it because language is arbitrary?

Is it because native speakers Use it both ways?

Is there any grammatical base for this use?

It is not a duplicate of "flood" or " a flood" since I showed the example of fish.

Comment: Just because a word is countable in one sense, it doesn't mean that it is countable in all senses. See definition 2.3 of [water](https://www.lexico.com/en/definition/water) in Lexico.

Comment: @PeterShor.That comes under arbitrariness of language

Comment: Related: 1. [“The colour of (the) water(s)”](https://ell.stackexchange.com/questions/20518/the-colour-of-the-waters) 2. [What does “tossing waters” mean?](https://ell.stackexchange.com/questions/67592/what-does-tossing-waters-mean)

Comment: @Mari-LouA.Is there any flaw in my question? is my question logical or not.Please feel free to answer

Comment: It's fine. I posted the links to help clarify your confusion, and because it's handy to have more than one related question in the linked column  for future visitors.

Comment: *"What will you all be drinking?" "Three coffees and two waters please."*

Comment: @JasonBassford.I have understood.you mean to say that uncountable nouns are countable in some informal contexts such as ordering items in a hotel.But in formal context they are uncountable.I am not arguing with you,please.

Comment: There are **many** flaws with your question. Example sentences should be put in a quote box, using the ">" character. Every sentence should begin with a capital letter and end with a terminating punctuation mark, and a blank space should come after that punctuation mark and not before. When you post sloppy questions, they are difficult to read and a chore to fix.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

The countable form used in the example, "waters" is poetic in use, and means "streams, rivers, lakes" collectively. Singular use in this sense is very rare, and archaic:

> And as they went on their waye, they cam unto a certayne water  (from an old translation of the Bible, in modern translations it is "river".)

In modern English this sense is only used poetically and only in the plural.

The plural can also be used for "regions of the sea" *The territorial waters of the UK* or "spa water" *take the waters at Tunbridge Wells*. In these senses it is always plural.

As a singular, it means "a serving of drinking water"  *I'll have a water and a beer, please. But even in this sense, it is rather rare. "A glass of water" or similar would more common.

In nearly all other use, water is uncountable.  Except in the rare cases described above, you don't use the plural "waters" or the countable singular "a water".

The word is unlike "fish" because "fish" is an acceptable plural of "fish".  The only acceptable plural of "water" is "waters". The word "water" is singular, never plural.

The expression "a little water" is not a use of a countable noun "a water", it is the compound determiner "a little", which modifies the uncountable noun "water".  Consider that you can't say "two little waters", because the compound word is "a little".

Comment: In the diom Still waters run deep, it is clearly plural.your answer is what I know. I think it is just a matter of usage which defies logic

Comment: It is clearly plural. This is the poetic usage in the first paragraph.  What is your question?

Comment: .If it is plural, there should be the use of  a water

Comment: No. That is not correct. There are some words that are only used in the plural in certain senses.

Comment: For example "Clothes" (in the sense of things you wear) is always plural. The singular "cloth" has a different meaning.

Comment: .clothes and cloth are two different words. water  and  waters mean almost the same

Comment: Let us [continue this discussion in chat](https://chat.stackexchange.com/rooms/98130/discussion-between-james-k-and-jagatha-v-l-narasimharao).

Comment: @JagathaVLNarasimharao: your arguments seem to amount to "English should be the way **I** think it should be". English (like every other language) is the way it is, not the way you or I or anybody think it should be.

Comment: @ColinFine.I am not saying that language should be the way I think it should be.As I studied linguistics a bit I feel  language is arbitrary which defies logic some times