# Noun both countable and uncountable

Tags: uncountable-nouns, countable-nouns

For example, *gas* is countable and uncountable. Then, can 'much gas' always be translated into 'many gases'? Oh, look at that! there's a cloud of many gases!

Comment: This should answer your question, as 'gas' and 'gases' is the same issue as with 'water' and 'waters'. [Water, a water and waters](https://ell.stackexchange.com/questions/222769/water-a-water-and-waters)

Comment: No, I mean a word that can be countable and uncountable.

Comment: And I want to express uncountable nouns' senses with countable nouns.

Comment: Yes, 'gas' and 'water' can be used the same way. You can say "some gas" or "some water"; you can say "gases" and "waters" and in very specific contexts you can say "a water".

Comment: @Astralbee When I use a plural noun, should it mean different types? The answer below says it does.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Much gas refers to a large amount, possibly of only one type. Many gases refers to many different types of gas, for example hydrogen, helium, chlorine, nitrogen, water vapour, etc. Both can be correct in different contexts, but they are not interchangeable.

Comment: Should it be necessarily different types? or generally?

Comment: I can't think of a situation where you would talk about 2 gases if they were the same type of gas.

Comment: Just imagine a cloud of some gases. The same type.

Comment: Then you wouldn't use the plural.

Comment: But we use 'ashes.' One type.

Comment: or a veil of mists

Comment: Ash and ashes are pretty much equivalent. You can clean out the ash from a fire or the ashes from a fire - it means the same. But you wouldn't use "many ashes" unless they were different samples or different types.

Comment: We don't say 'a veil of mists' - mist is a substance. (Admittedly, we do say 'lost in the mists of time', but that's a metaphor.) Supposing you could see a cloud of gas, you wouldn't know from looking at it how many types of gas there were in it.